# JFileChooser Save Dialog shows overlaping open and save button text

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, uimanager

I'm using the following code to display save file dialog.

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
retval = fc.showSaveDialog(jinternalFrame);
```

When i select a folder/drive once the JFilechooser opens, the save and open button overlaps for a few seconds and goes off as soon as you hover over the button.

[image]

How do i resolve this?

Comment: I have edited the question. Its 'JInternalFrame'.

Comment: `JInternalFrame` is the name of a class, you can't pass it as parameter. Please use real code that actually reproduces your problem. Also, is the problem reproduced when you just pass `null`?

Comment: I was passing an instance of JInternalFrame. I tried pass null, but that does not solve the problem